# Removing login privlages for a person in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2

I am fairly new to the whole SSRS system in SQL.  There is a person in our system that has not worked here in years and my boss has given me the task of removing their login from all the reports, and I would rather not have to do it one by one.  Is there some way or process that I can use to remove their credentials?  Mainly just need to remove them from the report database.  They have already been disabled in active dir, so they can't get onto the system anymore, but this is more of a cosmetic cleanup of people no longer with the company.

Thanks in advance for the help

Comment: Have you verified the user had individual access to each report?  The normal thing to do would have been to grant them access through an AD group, so when you remove them from AD, they lose access to the report.

Comment: The user has individual access to a lot of the reports because they were the primary report writer.  They are the only one to have been given individual rights.  Everyone else has been setup thru AD groups.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well if you have already disabled them in AD, then they should not be able to login to the server now.  If you are just looking to cleanup the names, then you try this query.

```
DELETE FROM [ReportServer].[dbo].[PolicyUserRole]
WHERE UserID IN
(
 SELECT UserID FROM Users WHERE UserName ='blabla'
)

DELETE FROM Users WHERE UserName ='blabla'
```